# How to ensure thread safe in iocp receive?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, winsock, iocp

```
DWORD bytes;
ULONG_PTR key; ChatOverlappedData* ol;
if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hComp_, &bytes, &key, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&ol, 0)) {
    return false;
}
int type = ol->getNetType();
if (type == net::kAction_Accept) {
    onAccept(ol, bytes, key);
} else if (type == net::kAction_Recv) {
    onRecv(ol, bytes, key);
} else if (type == net::kAction_Send) {

} 
return true;
```

Consider following scenario,

client `alice` sent two command to the server, which is made up of three data package, `p1` `p2` `p3`. The first two package form the first command `c1`, the third package form the second command `c2`. In the function `onRecv`, the server need to push the data packages to some kind of command buffer to form complete commands.

But suppose there are three threads `t1` `t2` `t3`, each thread get a data package(`p1`, `p2`, `p3`) from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`,

Since windows is a preemptive operating system, thread `t2` could run before `t1`, `t3`. The result command buffer would be `p2`->`p1`->`p3` or `p2`->`p3`->`p1`.

How to ensure the thread safe for the action of pushing the data package to the command buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to only attempt one overlapped I/O request per socket in each direction. So post a single overlapped read operation, and when it completes, post another one when you finish processing the first one.

Posting more than one such operation is extremely complex because even though the completions will be posted in order, the threads processing the completions may execute out of order and you have to do some painful and complicated tracking.

The benefit from posting multiple overlapped operations in the same direction for the same connection is very, very small. It's almost never sufficient to justify the additional complexity. For servers that handle large numbers of connections, it's usually not worth doing at all because the extra memory consumption (or use of smaller buffer sizes) can actually make performance worse.

The main benefits of IOCP are more efficient discovery of which connections need work and the efficient assignment of that work to a pool of threads. This is what makes the difference between servers that max out at 800 connections and servers that can handle 10,000 connections without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Your answer to *"How do I use asynchronous I/O?"* is *"Use synchronous I/O instead. It's easier."*? Gee, that's really helpful.

Comment: No, not at all. The I/O is still asynchronous. The operation is posted and completes later.

Comment: thanks, `https://github.com/Jichao/chatserver/blob/master/chatserver/CommandCenter.cpp` is my implementation right?

Comment: That code appears to post only one receive operation at a time, AFAICT.

Comment: Serializing I/O over an asynchronous channel is conceptually the same as using synchronous I/O. Except, now **you** also have to implement the synchronization. Sounds like a lose-lose situation to me.

Comment: Huh? Say you're handling 1,000 clients. You have 1,000 asynchronous receive operations posted. Say two of them send you data. Two of those operations complete and the completions are dispatched to two threads out of your pool for you. What more do you want exactly? What are you comparing that to? 1,000 threads blocked on synchronous operations?

Comment: IMO, iocp mainly solve the context-switch burden. Serializing I/O should not hurt the performance a lot.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's a good way to deal with this issue. However, say that a client is sending you a file in chunks along with some other command, say, a chat message that will be displayed on some control. When you receive chunks from file, you have to save that to disk. In this case, the chat message will slow down if the disk writes operation takes long time to finish because you have to postpone **WSARecv** call until write on disk completes. How do you deal with this issue?

Comment: @amaninlove You don't have to wait until the write to disk completes. You only have to wait until you have read the received data from the socket. I usually handle this by having a new read be posted as soon as the protocol message is parsed. Processing the protocol message can go in parallel with receiving more data from the socket.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But that will cause the memory usage to go very high if you just keep reading without a pause because you now have to issue new reads with new buffers and so older buffers have to be freed once write to disk finishes.

Comment: @amaninlove You definitely do want to put a limit on how much work you accumulate and throttle receiving if it gets too large. A simple rule is to not dispatch a new request for a client until the previous request completes. This is easily implemented by using a flag that indicates whether a client's request has been dispatched or not. If that flag is set to true, don't dispatch a thread to do the new request. When the thread working the existing request finishes it, it can queue any "next request" from that same connection.

Comment: @amaninlove Though you could do it, I never throttle an incoming connection and always receive data from it. If too much unprocessed data accumulates, I disconnect that client to "punish" it for overruning the server. This shifts the client the obligation to throttle data being sent if responses aren't being receive. For many protocols, that's appropriate. Generally, I believe in shifting as much work to the client as can be shifted to it so that the server scales as much as possible. That's, of course, not always appropriate.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh so you are talking about a protocol that only sends a chunk if it was requested to. My protocol actually keeps sending chunks from file after only 1 initial request.

Comment: @amaninlove With no acknowledgements from the server at all? In that case, the only thing the client can do is send as soon as possible. An "always receive if possible" design may cause almost the entire file to sit in memory. An option in this case is to set a maximum buffer size and have the write thread advance the "last byte written" count and the IO posting code track a "last byte received" and not post a new receive if the different is too great.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Wouldn't acknowledging of each chunk cause an overhead/bandwidth issues?

Comment: @amaninlove No. Reply packets are being sent constantly anyway (for TCP-level ACKs) so it's effectively free.